# Magnetic dipole moment of $^3$Li$^7$ nucleus

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

In a quantum book I am reading for self-study it is noted that the magnetic dipole moment of the $^3$Li$^7$ **nucleus** can be calculated as

$\mu = 1.67 \times 10^{-26} J\cdot T^{-1}.$

However there is not an explanation as to where this figure comes from. It seems like perhaps one should consider the structure of $^3$Li$^7$ in some way as to calculate the magnetic moment in a similar way to the Bohr magnetron? Besides this I'm at a loss here with how to arrive at this value for $\mu$, can anyone please explain where this comes from?

Comment: [Possibly relevant](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/118518/44126); I haven't checked whether you can use an alpha-triton cluster the way I used an alpha-deuteron cluster in that answer.  What book?  Is there a calculation method described nearby?  What methods have you tried?

Comment: $$ \mu_{dipole} \approx \frac{e \hbar}{\mu_{mass}} $$